# Fix for biblatex-MLA in TeX Live 2011

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

I'm trying to fix an error I get when trying to use biblatex-mla 0.9.5 with Biblatex 1.7

Unfortunately, I get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \biburldatelong
```

Which I believe was a supported command in earlier Biblatex versions. Failing this, is there any other way I can get MLA-style citations using Biblatex and Biber?

Comment: Are you using long dates?  If not, what happens if you use `\providecommand\biburldatelong{}` after loading `biblatex`?  (Sorry, I'd need to download `biblatex-mla` to test a more robust solution.)

Comment: @jon nope, and that seems to have fixed it. Can you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Sure.  I added a brief answer.  But someone may still come along with a real one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one possible workaround would be to add

```
\providecommand{\biburldatelong}{}
```

after `biblatex` is loaded.  But this is not a robust solution, especially (I imagine) if one is using long form dates.